# Why is _.difference returning all the items?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two lists, `oldPanodatas` and `newPanodatas`. I want to get only the objects in `newPanodatas` that aren't present in `oldPanodatas`. I did this:

```
var filteredPanodatas = _.difference(newPanodatas, oldPanodatas)
```

But I'm getting all the items, `_.difference` is not filtering anything whatsoever:

```
OLD: Object {roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", x: 262, index: 1, y: 211, panoDataRotate: 0…}
OLD: Object {roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", x: 177, index: 0, y: 182, panoDataRotate: 0…}
NEW: Object {index: 0, x: 177, y: 182, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}
NEW: Object {index: 1, x: 262, y: 211, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}
NEW: Object {index: 2, x: 200, y: 200, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}
FILTERED: Object {index: 0, x: 177, y: 182, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}
FILTERED: Object {index: 1, x: 262, y: 211, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}
FILTERED: Object {index: 2, x: 200, y: 200, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}
```

Why is this? What's the correct way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with [`differceWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith), the `isEqual` comparator which is invoked to compare elements of array to values

```
_.differenceWith(newPanodatas, oldPanodatas, _.isEqual);
```

Code sample,

```
var old = [{roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", x: 262, index: 1, y: 211, panoDataRotate: 0},  {roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", x: 177, index: 0, y: 182, panoDataRotate: 0}];
newobj = [{index: 0, x: 177, y: 182, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}, {index: 1, x: 262, y: 211, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}, {index: 2, x: 200, y: 200, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", panoDataRotate: 0}];
r = _.differenceWith(newobj, old, _.isEqual);
```

The result of `r`

```
[{index: 2, panoDataRotate: 0, roomModelId: "56a9e0088ac247005538d6d3", x: 200, y: 200}]
```

Comment: Weird, for some reason the `FILTERED:` console log doesn't log anymore if I use your code.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/ezywL686/1/ (I changed the filtering code since I need to filter the items by index). As you can see, the last `console.log()` doesn't log anything.

Comment: @alex, add `return` in this line `return !_.find(oldPanodatas, {index: item.index})`